# Including a for loop in an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, for-loop

I'm building an application in which I want to display some errors when a user enters invalid values in an input box. A correct value is appended as 'entry' to a div if no errors were found. In total there are 3 cases when to display errors:

1. The input value is empty
2. The input value is a number
3. The input value already exists

These errors are displayed with `if else` statements.
1.and 2. were easy, but the problem case (3.) only validates against the first element of class `.cat_entry`.

```js
if(cat_input == '') { // generate errors
        errorDisplay(error_input_empty);
    } else if(!isNaN(cat_input)) {
        errorDisplay(error_input_number);
    } else if($('.cat_entry') == cat_input) { // THIS IS  THE PROBLEMATIC LINE
        // .cat_entry is the class of the entries that have been appended
        errorDisplay(error_duplicate);
    } else {
        // stuff
    };
```

So I believe I need a for loop/ .each() (no problem so far), but how do I include this as a condition in an if statement? Something like.. `if( for(i=0;i<$('.cat_entry').length;i++) { ... };` ... How to return true (or something similar) when one of the entries matches the input value, then pass the return value to the if statement?

**EDIT:** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LvyG9/) is a jsFiddle with the relevant code. I **updated** it with $.inArray() method. I'd like to try and use this instead of a for / .each() loop.

Comment: do the loop before the `if`, put the result in a variable, and check the variable. You can't put a loop inside the condition of an if.

Comment: well, the only other way you could do it, is by creating a function that takes cat_input and $('.cat_entry') as parameters, and does the loop, return false if the value already exists or return true if the loop ends normally. But semantically, it would be almost the same as what dave said, instead of a variable you use a function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add this to the function:

```js
var isDuplicate = false;
$('.cat_entry').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).text().indexOf(cat_input)) {
    isDuplicate = true;
}
// And in the if else loop:
else if(isDuplicate == true)
//and just before the function ends
isDuplicate = false;
```

Thanks to all for the help you offered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var a=$('.cat_entry'),o={};
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
  var s=a[i].val();
  if(s in o){
    errorDisplay(error_duplicate);
    return;
  }
  o[s]=true;
}
```

or

```
var o={};
$('.cat_entry').each(function(){
  var s=$(this).val();
  if(s in o){
    errorDisplay(error_duplicate);
    return;
  }
  o[s]=true;
}
```

Comment: I half-tested this, but needed to change `$(this).val()` to `$(this).innerHTML()` (.html, .text, .val() didn't work), but what value should I pass so that the rest of the validation tests only continue if this is false? In other words, how do you connect this to the rest of the function? (The entire test fiddle is in the link in the OP)

Comment: could you please elaborate @ic3b3rg?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the jQuery `inArray` function for this, such as:

```
else if($.inArray(cat_input, $('.cat_entry') != -1) 

}
```

Comment: For some reason, when I do this, the input never validates, even if no match is found. Thanks for letting me know about the inArray method though.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle with your code / array? The inArray function should work for you, it'll just need to have the right values to check against.

Comment: inArray returns `-1` on failure, not 0. You need to add `!=-1`

Comment: Okay, I linked to a jsFiddle in the original post. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ChrisDixon , could you please have a look at the fiddle?

Comment: Apologies, I was out for the rest of the day! It sounds like you've worked it out though now :)